# How can I access Windows SBS 2008 without the admin domain password or boot disk?

Tags: passwords, admin, password-recovery, small-business-server

I have an old Dell Poweredge T100 from my fathers old business running Windows Small Business server 2008, however I do not know the admin password nor do I have the boot/windows install disk. Is there any possible way to access the server or reset the admin password? Bare in mind, i'm not a tech wizzard, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsofts official answer to this would be no, but someone on their forums linked to this, hopefully it helps.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2011/08/15/reset-your-windows-sever-2008-r2-domain-controller-administrator-password.aspx

> NOTE: This is for Windows Server 2k8 r2, so it may not carry over to
>   SBS.

1. Restart your Windows server 2008 DC with the installation CD
2. Choose your language and click **next**
3. Select your partition and installation version and click **Next**
4. Click on **Comm and Line Prompt**
5. Change directory to the access the system 32 directory. Then your original **C:/drive** is changed to D: or E: depending on the number of drive and partitions you have on that system.
6. Rename the file **Utilman.exe** to **Utilman.exe.bak** using the **comm and Copy** **Utilman.exe Utilman.exe.bak**.
7. Using Command **Move Cmd.exe Utilman.exe** to move **CMD.exe** file into **Utilman.exe**. Press **O** or **Y** to accept after that restart your Computer normaly
8. At the user logon screen, press a combination of **Windows KEY+U**, then the **CMD.exe** will appear. Type **net user “Username””new password”**;

Then your system Admin Password is reset. Please don’t forget to rename back Utilman. Exe ->Cmd.exe and Utilman.exe.bak-> Utilman.exe after getting back access.

Comment: Unfortunately I lack the Installation disk so Im stuck at point 1. But thankyou for the information

Comment: If you are able to burn a CD/DVD, microsoft offers a trial version that may get the job done- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15237

Comment: I ended up booting from Ubuntu on a USB for the time being and I can see some files, is it possible to change the admin password files this way?

Comment: @DerrekM6554 you may be able to do those first few steps (renaming files) and then booting it up in windows again to see if it worked.

Comment: I guess I will give that a try then. Unfortunately now the server keeps turning on and off repeatedly when I plug it into the mains and I have no idea why.